# Syntax Errors in the test class/client code

Tags: java, class, syntax, constructor

I am trying to create a Rectangle class that has overloaded constructors. The first constructor requires no parameters. The second has two parameters, one for length and a second for width. Member variables store the length and width of the rectangle, and member methods assign and retrieve the length and width and return the area and perimeter of the rectangle. The class needs to be tested by writing appropriate client code. The problem is that there are many syntax errors in the code that I do not know how to solve.

public class Rectangle {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
          private int length;
          private int width;

          Rectangle(){
            this.length=1; // assuming default length=1
            this.width=1; // assuming default width=1
          }

          Rectangle(int length, int width){
            this.length=length; 
            this.width=width; 
          }

        int area(){
           return length*width;
        }
        int perimeter(){
          return 2*(length+width);
        }
        }


        // test class

        public class TestRectangle{
            public static void main(String args[]){
                Rectangle r1= new Rectangle();
                System.out.println("Area of r1: "+ r1.area());
                Rectangle r2= new Rectangle(2,3);
                System.out.println("Perimetr of r2: "+ r2.perimeter());
            }
        }

}
```

}

Comment: Why are you trying to redefine class Rectangle within the main method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need two classes, but you can't define a class within a method like that.

Start with just one class, and then if you want to separate them, you need two files

```
public class Rectangle {
    private int length;
    private int width;

    Rectangle() {
        this.length = 1; // assuming default length=1
        this.width = 1; // assuming default width=1
    }

    Rectangle(int length, int width) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    int area() {
        return length * width;
    }

    int perimeter() {
        return 2 * (length + width);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
        System.out.println("Area of r1: " + r1.area());
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(2, 3);
        System.out.println("Perimetr of r2: " + r2.perimeter());
    }
}
```

And writing a main method isn't proper testing. For that, you should prefer to use at least Junit